# Array Issue Not Printing Middle or Median

Tags: java

I want user to be able to add number(s) to an array until a predetermined `randomNumber` has been entered. Then I want to print the middle and median of the array.

The code works for the user inputs but I get nothing from the middle or median, it just says `0`.

Could anyone please help me with this? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayTest {
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    int usersGuess;       
    int randomNumber = 45;

public void enterNumbers() {
    do {
        System.out.printf("Please enter numbers: ");
        usersGuess  = input.nextInt();

        if ( usersGuess != randomNumber ) {
            System.out.printf("Please enter numbers: ");
            usersGuess  = input.nextInt();
        }
        else 
              System.out.println("Correct guess");
    } 
    while ( usersGuess != randomNumber );   

    int testArray []  = new int[ 20 ];

    boolean correctGuess = false;

    for ( int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++ ) {
        testArray[ i ] = usersGuess ;

        if ( testArray[ i ] == randomNumber ) {
            correctGuess = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println();System.out.println( "Middle is: " + testArray
            [ ( testArray.length + 1)/2] );

    Arrays.sort( testArray );

    System.out.println( "Median is: " + testArray[ testArray.length/2] );
    System.out.println();
}


public class Test {
    public static void main( String [] args ){
        ArrayTest arrayTest = new ArrayTest();
        arrayTest.enterNumbers();
    }
}
```

Comment: This question sounds like homework.  Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure if you do not know how to structure arrays then you should not be using the data structure ArrayList yet. Here is a completed version of the code without an ArrayList.

- arrays are final, as in they cannot be changed after creation. So in this example I used a max number of guesses

Hope this helps...

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ArrayTest 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        int usersGuess;       
        int randomNumber = 45;
         int num_of_guesses = 0;

         int max_guesses = 20;


        public void enterNumbers()
        {
            int testArray []  = new int[ max_guesses ];

             do
            {


                  if ( usersGuess != randomNumber )
                {
                    System.out.printf("Please enter numbers: ");
                    usersGuess  = input.nextInt();     

                }
                else 
                      System.out.println("Correct guess");

                  testArray[ num_of_guesses ] = usersGuess;
                  num_of_guesses++;

                  if ( num_of_guesses >= max_guesses)
                {
                    System.out.println("Your all out of guesses!");
                    break;     
                } 

            } 
            while ( usersGuess != randomNumber &&  max_guesses >= num_of_guesses );

            System.out.println( "\nMiddle is: " + testArray
                    [ ( num_of_guesses)/ 2] );

            Arrays.sort( testArray, 0, num_of_guesses );


            System.out.println( "Median is: " + testArray[ ( num_of_guesses)/ 2 ] );
            System.out.println();

        }

    }

    public class Test 
    {
        public static void main( String [] args )
        {
            ArrayTest arrayTest = new ArrayTest();

            arrayTest.enterNumbers();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not saving off the user's guesses.  You need to be adding their guesses to your `testArray` in your first `do while` loop.

This should work for you:

```
public void enterNumbers()
{
    List<Integer> guesses = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    do  
    {   
        System.out.printf("Please enter numbers: "); 
        usersGuess  = input.nextInt();
        guesses.add(usersGuess);

        if ( usersGuess != randomNumber )
        {   
            System.out.printf("Please enter numbers: "); 

        }   
        else 
              System.out.println("Correct guess");   

    }   
    while ( usersGuess != randomNumber );

    int size = guesses.size();
    System.out.println("\nMiddle is: " + guesses.get((size + 1) / 2);

    Collections.sort(guesses);

    System.out.println("Median is: " + guesses.get(size / 2));
    System.out.println();
}
```